# How to change a TABLE name like "exampletablename" to "$exampletablename"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to make this code working? I have the code:

```
$tablename = $user_data['id'];

$sql= "CREATE TABLE ".$tablename." (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
YO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
DESTINATARIO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
MENSAJE VARCHAR(100),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

I wana create a TABLE for every client, and i whant the id to be the table name.
The problem is that every time i use $tablename as a table name, like in the example, i got this error:

*"Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"35599"*".

If I change the $tablename with a value like "35599" for example, is creating the table perfectly. Any one knows how to use a the "$tablename" on the sql request?

Comment: `**$tablename**` does not make any sense. It has to be just `$tablename`. _And you have to escape the content of that variable.

Comment: Apart from this it is _very_ questionable to dynamically create tables per user. The typical and clean approach is to use a reference column to associate entries in a shared table with a specific user account.

Comment: sorry,  is not **$tablename** ... is only $tablename

Comment: If the table name is a number or a reserved word or has spaces in the name it has to be enclosed in 2 backticks chars: ``. And please take into account arkascha's comment

Comment: if possible you can use some prefix with user id , like this $sql= "CREATE TABLE dd_".$tablename." (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
YO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
DESTINATARIO VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
MENSAJE VARCHAR(100),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";

Comment: It woks!  With backticks chars `` and a prefix. Works perfectly !! TNX  arkascha, Zimmi and aniket ashtekar !!!

Comment: You better listen to other advice.

Comment: i wanna use the tablee as a as a chat message. if every person wil have 2.000.000 messages and i have 100.000 members, i wil have to many colums. Thast why i wana crate a table for every Member. Do you this that's a bad idea? do i have to make only one table "chat" for all the messeges from ol the members?

Comment: 100k tables is a terrible idea

Comment: ... That's true...!

Comment: Have a look at [database-normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Using a single table you need only a few columns. That reference I was talking about is _one single column_ holding a user id. What is true is that you will have millions of entries in that table. But that is not an issue at all for a good RDBMS, provided you use good indexes.